# Is "daily sacrifice" (H8548) in Daniel 8:11-13; 11:31; 12:11; an accurate rendering?

Tags: translation-philosophy, daniel

When doing a word study of H8548, it speaks of something that is "constantly", in reference to the shewbread, the light of the candles in the holy place, and other references. It seems to be more connected with the continuing of, or the constant transgression that is spoken of in Daniel 9:24. That must be finished.

Are the translators adding the word sacrifice because they are not aware of the context; it seems like they are trying to fit these scriptures with Daniel 9:27, and were trying to make sense of it. Below is my translation of certain scriptures which seem to be more consistent, while I still can't make total sense of what is being said, so follow me.

Daniel 9:24

> 70 weeks are determined to restrain (H3607; cp. 2 Thessalonians 2:6) the transgression.

Daniel 8:12

> the host were given over to the horn, because of the "continual transgression", that he may cast down the truth to the ground and prosper.

Daniel 12:11

> And from the time of the departure [which seems to be the transgression] (H5493 departed, Daniel 9:5; 11:31; cp. 2 Thessalonians 2:3); to the continual setting up of the abomination of desolation shall be 1290 days. (Revelation 14:11).

Referencing from "A Biblical Theology of Leviticus" by Michael Morales concerning the context of scriptures surrounding H8548: “If the light beamed forwards it would have fallen on the table of shewbread, where twelve loaves of bread, symbolizing the twelve tribes of Israel, were heaped up (Leviticus 24:5–9).

> Light and fire represent the life-giving presence and blessing of God (e.g. Exodus 13:21–22). Thus, Aaron had to arrange the lamps so that their light always illuminated the shewbread. This arrangement portrayed visually God’s intention that his people should live continually in his presence and enjoy the blessing mediated by his priests.

So, could the use of (H8548) in Daniel have more of the meaning, concerning their dependence upon the foreign leader, rather than God; which would be the departure? And will come to its full end with the actual worship of this ruler (Daniel 11:22, 30,32; Rev.13.12)?

Answer (score 0):

The operative word in all the OP's passages is תָּמִיד (tamid) which simply means "continual" as an adjective.  "Daily sacrifice" is a highly interpretive translation.

In the book of Daniel, the word תָּמִיד (tamid), meaning continual or regular, occurs just five times, Dan 8:11, 12, 13, 11:31, 12:11 as an adverb. It is always associated with the apostate power that removed this “continual” from the sanctuary.

The same word occurs almost 100 times in the rest of the OT. It is often associated with various things in the sanctuary such as:

- The shew bread which was to be on the table continually, Ex 25:30, Lev 24:8, Num 4:7, 16, 2 Chron 2:4
- The menorah which was to burn continually, Ex 27:20, Lev 24:2-4
- The High Priests’ breast plate as a continual memorial, Ex 28:29, 30
- The High Priests’ blue ribbon attached to his turban as a continual reminder of the presence of God, Ex 28:37, 38
- The morning and evening sacrifice of a burnt offering (a lamb) on the sanctuary altar, Ex 29:41, 42, Num 28:3-6, 10, 15, 23, 24, 31, 29:6, 11, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 1 Chron 16:37, 40, 2 Chron 24:14, Ezra 3:5, Neh 10:33, Ps 50:8, Eze 46:15
- The burning wood in the altar of offering, continually, Ex 30:8, Lev 6:13
- Offering of fine flour was to be continual, Lev 6:20, Neh 10:33, Eze 46:14
- The continual presence of the cloud over the sanctuary, Num 9:16
- The blowing continually of trumpets, 1 Chron 16:6
- The ceremonies of the sanctuary, generally, that operated continually, 1 Chron 16:37, 23:31.

Note two important things about this survey:

1. There is MUCH more than just the continual/regular (morning and evening) burnt offering of a lamb associated with the word תָּמִיד (tamid); however, that is the most common. תָּמִיד (tamid) is also associated with shew bread, the light (menorah), the High Priests’ breast plate, the blue ribbon, fire on the altar, grain offering, trumpeting, sanctuary services generally.
2. All the features associated with the תָּמִיד (tamid), “continual” are taken up in the NT as symbols of the ministry of Jesus as our High Priest both here and in heaven, Heb 4:14-16, 7:23-28, 8:1, 2, 9:1-28, 10:1-18.

Note also the following:

- Jesus was the fulfilment of what the sanctuary/temple typified, John 2:19-21, Heb 9:1-28, 10:1-18
- Jesus represented the foundation of the temple as well, 1 Peter 2:4-8 (Compare Isa 28:16, Ps 118:22)
- Jesus was the bread of life, John 6:35, 41, 48 (compare Ex 25:23-30, Lev 24:8).
- Jesus was the light of life, John 8:12, 9:5 (compare the lampstand Ex 25:31-39, Lev 24:3, 4, Isa 53:11, Ps 56:13, etc)
- Jesus was the Passover Lamb and thus the promised Messiah, John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 12:1-14).
- Jesus is the High Priest of the New Covenant in fulfilment of the Levitical covenant, Heb 4:14-16, 7:23-28, because He was “pure, blameless, set apart” exactly as the Levites were. See also Heb 9:15, 12:24.
- Even the blue cord signifying the presence of God was fulfilled in and of Jesus, John 14:10, 11, etc.
- Jesus provided the blood of the new covenant of which the communion ceremony was to be a memorial, Matt 26:28, Mark 14:24, Luke 22:20, 1 Cor 11:25, Heb 13:20, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 24:5, 8).

Now back to Daniel and his תָּמִיד (tamid). Many of the English versions add “sacrifice” after “continual” or "daily" - is this valid? Yes and no! “Yes” if we understand it refers to the sanctuary ceremonies generally; “no” of we understand it refers to the sacrifices exclusively. I believe that Daniel is alluding to all the sanctuary imagery/symbolism that pointed to Jesus and His perfect ministry as our intercessor (1 Tim 2:5, Heb 8:6, 12:24, etc).

Thus, the most accurate translation of תָּמִיד (tamid) is "continual", or, "regular".  Neither "daily", nor, "sacrifice" is innate in the meaning of this word.

Comment: Only in 9.27 is there a bringing to an end, (H7673)specifically the sacrifice, in reference to your comment. The continual, is linked to 7311,so it seems you are making the same connection the translators are but it's not there if you really look.

Comment: Unless H7673 and 7311,  are being said to be used as synonyms, which they don't really mean the same, I can't see any other reason for that interpretation. And a possible historical assumption concerning Antiochus IV.

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory - That Messiah would end sacrifice is clear from the ripping of the temple curtain at Jesus death.  But that has nothing to do with the meaning of tamid.  Indeed, the word does not even occur in Dan 9.

Answer (score 0):

The translation of (H8548, tamiyd) found in (Dan.8:11-13;11:31;12:11) rendered: “the daily sacrifice”; which has the insertion of the word “sacrifice”. Due to the grammatical links found in Dan.9:27 where "sacrifice" occurs; the links are “abomination” (H8251; cp.9:27; 11:31; 12:11), and “desolation” (H8074; 8:13;11:31;12:11). By this insertion, other words have been mistranslated according to their regular use within the book of Dainel; the primary example of this; is (H5493), which is translated “even by departing” and also, “and has departed” in Daniel.9:5,11; whereas, in 11:31;12:11; it has been alternatively rendered “take away” which misleads the reader to think, that this is the same event as the “sacrifice” “that is to cease” (H7673) in 9:27.

Furthermore, stemming from (H8548) being found in 8:11; the word (H7311), has been alternatively rendered “taking away”; which is inconsistent with its primary meaning of “exaltation” within the book of Daniel.11:12;36; along with erroneously linking (H7311); to (H5493); making them seem synonymous, which loses the authors intention in translation, and misguides the reader.

Below is a rendering in which the words are translated according to consistent contextual use, within the book of Daniel; which are supported by refenced, allowing one to properly order the events described within these texts; giving clarity for a more accurate interpretation.

70 weeks are determined… to restrain/finish (H3607[1]; cp. 2Thes.2:6-7[2]) the transgression (H6588[3]). (Dan.9:24).

1# Depart continually. Dan. 11.30: for shall come against him the ships of Cyprus, therefore he shall be grieved, and return and denounce over the holy convent, so shall he deal (make a treaty), and in returning, have understanding from those who forsake the holy covenant v31 “arms by him, shall serve, and shall arise, and begin[4] the sanctuary with strength[5]; then they shall depart continually; being given over[6] to the abomination of desolation. (2Thes. 2:9-12).

2# Exalted continually. Dan.8:10: And it grew to host of the heavens, and it cast down some to ground: some of the host, and some of the stars; overcoming them. v.11 As the chief of the host, great by the some will he be exalted continually, casting down the place of his (God’s) sanctuary.

3# Continual transgression v.12 the host were given over to him, because of continual transgression, that he may cast down truth and prospered

4# The continual transgression of the desolation v.13…How long will be the vision of the continual transgression of the desolation, the giving both of the sanctuary, and the hosts to be trampled on, and he said to me, 2300 evenings, and mornings, then shall be made righteous[7] the holy[8].

[1] H3607, Gen.8:2

[2] 2Thes.2:4; contextual relation.p.11:36.

[3] The transgression is the link in the 70 weeks that the translators should of focused on in 8:12-13; which is the subject of H8548, in the prophecy.

[4]H2490, only one occurrence in Dan. Cp. Gen.4:26.

[5] H4581; 11:39; cp. Isa.23:4.

[6] H5414 Dan.1:2; 11:11

[7]H6663, Dan.12:3

[8] H6944